# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to get python to read a row from a csv, and then place the contents into DynamoDB, then do the same with each subsequent row, until the end. I've modified Amazon's example code so that it reads like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import decimal
import pandas as pd

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', aws_access_key_id='123456789', aws_secret_access_key='987654321')

table = dynamodb.Table('Loyalty_One')

data = pd.read_csv('testdb.csv')
data[['collector_key']] = data[['collector_key']].astype(float)

for i, rows in data.iterrows():
    collector_key = float(data['collector_key'])
    sales = float(data['sales'])

    print("Adding data:", collector_key, sales)

    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'collector_key': collector_key,
            'sales': sales,
           }
       )
```

When I do, I get the error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to

You can see the file here, it's nothing out of the ordinary: 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/vshideler-data/testdb.csv

It seems to me that line 16 (and 17) should be extracting the contents of each row in the column. I thought that it might be possible that the header is interfering but doing pd.read_csv with "header=None" just gets me a different error altogether.

(although it occurs to me that I can probably just use the original dataframe instead of a csv file)

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: That's not really helpful. What's the problematic part of my post?

Comment: Did you try changing this float(data['collector_key']) for this data[['collector_key']].astype(float)

Comment: This works (thank you) but then I get the same error for line 17. I tried altering the format to "sales = (data[['sales']])" but then I get the error: "TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>" for value "       collector_key"




Trying "sales = data[['sales']].astype(float)" gets the error: TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>" for value "        sales

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be helpful.

If the type of the item is Series and have a single number. You can cast the type with conventional casting.

For example, You can cast like this...

```
XX=AA[AA.SHOUT="HAHA"]["TYPE"] # Get the Type column and find value...
XX=float(XX) if len(XX)==1 else np.NaN
print(XX)
```

In the real serious code, you have to check more exceptions but for the limited scenario it would be the easiest way to convert data.

Good Luck